# Displaying value only once

Tags: javascript, html, mustache

I am new to jquery and js. I have this simple thing trying to achieve but is not working.

Basically I am getting a collection of records and for age I want it to display only once..

```
<tr>
 {{#each items}}
     <td>{{=age}}</td>
  {{/}}
 </tr>
```

This works fine, but it displays value of age multiple times because of #each. I tried to remove #each etc. nothing works. Please help.
Thanks

Comment: javascript/jquery tags are very confusing here

Comment: How is Java involved?

Comment: This doesn't look like Javascript or jQuery to me.

Comment: You should point out that you are using "mustache".

Comment: please create a fiddle

Comment: So none of the tags are correct? Someone who know what this it, please tag it with something relevant.

Comment: .each() is a jquery function. Please visit  http://api.jquery.com/?s=each

Comment: Tags are correct it is working fine only it displays multiple times the value because of each function. I just want to figure out if there is a way in jquery/js to get it one time. I work with .net and it is so simple in it. Here?? is this for real java no offense.

Answer (score 0):

create a javascript array and populate it only if it does not already exist.

```
var arrValues[];

if (arrValues.indexOf(age) < 0) { arrValue.push(age); }
```